# Acquiring events a user created

Tags: facebook-fql

Im trying to use FQL, to retrieve all of the events the user is organising from Facebook.

I started off with using the example of FQL on Facebook Developer page. All worked well.

While aknowledging that the creator is not indexible, I really want to know how to retrieve the data.

what I tried is:

```
$fbuser = [facebook_user_id]
$fql = 'SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE creator='.$fbuser.' AND eid=*';
$ret_obj = $connection->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql, ));
echo '<pre>'.print_r($ret_obj).'</pre>';
```

How can I avoid this error "", while getting only the events, the user has created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

`fql?q=SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE creator=me() AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=me())`

The only caveat to this is you need to be participating in the event too.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I would think the creator is always going to participate in his own event, so that should do it..